# Improper integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2x) \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

How do you calculate the improper integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(2x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

You will get $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$ and would have to integrate that from $-\infty$ to $0$, however $\sin$ is also oscillates like $\cos$ therefore the limit to $-\infty$ doesn't exist.

Is this question answerable by odd or even function argument? But then again, the answer I checked online said that the limit was divergent. Hope anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: An improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ is said to exist if both $\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{0}^{M}f(x)\,dx$ and $\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^{0}f(x)\,dx$ exists and the improper integral is their sum . The odd function argument works only to give you the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral .

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question. It greatly helps the question visible to various search engines and hence is crucial for maintaining this community as a repository of mathematical knowledge. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As you already verified by yourself, $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\cos(2x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges, hence $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(2x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take two sequences $\{\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{4}\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ and $\{\frac{(4n+3)\pi}{4}\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ which both tend to infinity.

Then $$\int_{0}^{\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}{4}}\cos(2x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin(2\cdot\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin(\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$$ .

Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}{4}}\cos(2x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

But $$\int_{0}^{\dfrac{(4n+3)\pi}{4}}\cos(2x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin(\frac{(4n+3)\pi}{2})=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\dfrac{(4n+3)\pi}{4}}\cos(2x)\,dx=\frac{-1}{2}$$.

So the limit cannot be unique and hence the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(2x)\,dx$ diverges.

Hence $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x)\,dx$ does not exist.

Similarly $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)\,dx$ also does not exist. But we can define the principal value of the integral to be $0$.

This is because the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_{-M}^{M}\sin(x)\,dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\,0 = 0$ . But this does not mean that $\displaystyle\lim_{M,N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^{M}\sin(x)\,dx$ exist.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing I would do is let y= 2x so that dx= dy/2 and the integral becomes $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sin(y)dy$  It is then easy to calculate that $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} sin(y)dy= \frac{1}{2}\left[-cos(x)\right]_0^{2\pi}= 1$.  But sin(y) is periodic with period $2\pi$ so integrating from negative infinity to infinity we are adding infinitely many intervals on which the interal is 1.  Therefore $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sin(y)dy= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}sin(2x)dx$ DOES NOT CONVERGE.

Comment: I have no idea what this answer is trying to show. $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(y)\,dy = 0$ and not $1$ . If you are trying to say that you are adding intervals of the form $[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$ then again it does not makes sense as you are ending up with $1-1+1....$. You have to properly show that this series is divergent . A vague statement like "adding infintiely many intervals on which the integral is $1$ " does not make any sense. This is not a non-negative function .